# Как правильно подключить Microsoft_Windows_Themes в wpf

Tags: wpf

В одном проекте я использовал

```
xmlns:Microsoft_Windows_Themes="clr-namespace:Microsoft.Windows.Themes;assembly=PresentationFramework.Aero"
```

и всё работало отлично. Позже я создал новый проект, подключил эту строчку и ничего не работает. даже если полностью скопировать код со старого проекта ничего не работает. Возможно я что нибудь пропустил?

Comment: Надо еще и саму библиотеку подключить в References, какую — посмотрите в том проекте

Comment: @АндрейNOP а какое название библиотеки?

Comment: Я не нашел в своем старом проекте библиотеки

Comment: Ну сравните в двух проектах содержимое References

Answer (score 0):

Я добавил при помощи NuGet PresentationFramework.Aero2 недостающую библиотеку и потом подключил вот такой коммандой:

```
xmlns:Microsoft_Windows_Themes="clr-namespace:Microsoft.Windows.Themes;assembly=PresentationFramework.Aero"
```